# Change several layouts for different densities at the same time

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-xml

If I have three different layouts for a same view (lets say, one for phone, one for tablet and one for tablet in landscape) and I want to add/change a property that the three of them share (lets say, the `android:background`), is there a way of adding/changing it in one place and have it automatically in the other two layouts? Is there an alternative to copy-and-paste it?

Comment: If you change the value programmatically it will apply to the currently-used layout, which is presumably what you want?

Comment: I could use that for very specific moments, but not like a general rule. Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not really. You could have separate layouts for each set of elements and use `include` to include them in each subsequent layout, then just updating the single layout would update all of them. But this would mean having a lot of stand alone layouts. A good example of this is using a seperate `Toolbar` layout like so:

**Toolbar layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    style="@style/Toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

Then have this line in all layouts which you want to use `Toolbar`.

```
<include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
```

This technique could be applied to anything you like, and would allow you to in future only edit each separate layout once and have it applied everywhere you use it. You can also edit dimensions inside these Layouts under the include, or in code.

The only other way to achieve what you want would be to handle it all explicitly in code but I wouldn't recommend this.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `style` for the widget(TextView or LinearLayout for example) that uses `background` property and determine `background` property in that style.
Changing `background` property in `style` will affect all the widgets this style was previously applied to.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: Hum.. ok, my example was not very good, because yes, the `background` is something that would make sense to have is a style. I was more thinking in something in the direction that vguzzi suggested or maybe a plugin/functionality from Android Studio.